# Probability of getting a 1 from 1 die and 2 coins

Tags: probability, statistics

Say I  roll 1 die and 2 coins. What's the probability of getting a 1 on the die and anything for the 2 coins? I know you can count from the sample space and get the answer 4/24 or 1/6, but I wanted to try a way without counting.

The way I tried attempting it was P = ${3 \choose 1}$${\frac 16}{\frac 12}{\frac 12}$. Since there is 1 die and 2 coins there is 3 possible slots and since rolling 1 can be in any one of the slots I did ${3\choose 1}$. There is 1/6 chance of getting a 1 from a die and the other 2 slots could be either heads or tails thus ${\frac 16}{\frac 12}{\frac 12}$. But that gives ${\frac 3{24}}$ which is wrong

Can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the above equation (is it treating the events 1HT and 1TH as same maybe?).

Comment: $\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2}$ is the probability of a particular outcome (like 2HT or 3HH). The outcomes you want are 1HH, 1HT, 1TH, 1TT so you should just multiply by 4. I'm not sure why you are multiplying by 3; you don't need to consider the order of the three actions.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting a 1"?  Rolling a single die and flipping two coins you will get a number and two letters (H or T).  What constitutes "getting a 1"?  If you mean just a 1 on the die with anything on the coin flips, then is exactly the probability of throwing a 1 on a die, 1/6.  If that is two easy, let "n" represent the number that comes up on the die, the possible outcomes are nHH, nHT, nTH, nTT so 4 outcomes for each value of n with 6(4)= 24 total possible outcomes.  The probability  is 4/24= 1/6.

Comment: Forget about the coins, which play no role toward the desired event. As @user247327 says.

Comment: Ok so if instead it asked what's the probably of exactly 1 head then I'd just forget the die and it'd be 1/2? Or if it asked for 2 heads id still forget the die and it would just be 1/4?

Comment: @Jhin yes for your last comment.  In your original question you could have said $\frac16 \frac14 +\frac16 \frac12 +\frac16 \frac14= \frac16$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're treating the events $1TH$ and $1HT$ as the same event. Here's a formal solution:

Let $D$ be the event: the die toss result is $1$.

Let $E_i$ be the event: the toss of the $i$-th coin is either head or tail, for $i=1,2$

Note that the events $D, E_1, E_2$ are pairwise independent events, and that:
$$\text{Pr}(E_1)=\text{Pr}(E_2)=1, \ \ \text{Pr}(D)=\frac{1}{6} $$
What you're trying to compute is Pr$(D\cap E_1 \cap E_2), \ $  since the events are independent we have: $ \ \quad $ Pr$(D\cap E_1 \cap E_2)=$Pr$(D)\cdot $Pr$(E_1)\cdot $Pr$(E_2)=\frac{1}{6}\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{6}$